# Как найти первый встречный по оси Z объект?

Tags: unity3d

Есть наклейка, которую могу переместить по оси `X`, `Y`, зажимая кнопку мыши и таская эту наклейку. Мне нужно, чтобы после того, как я отпустил кнопку мыши, она прилепилась к ближайшему объекту по оси `Z`, а этих объектов на этой оси может быть несколько (z = 1, z = 2 и т.д). Пока что я использую вот такой костыль, но он мне дико не нравится:

```
public void OnMouseDrag () {
        Vector2 p = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (new Vector3 (Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y));
        gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3 (p.x, p.y, -1);
        gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider>().center = new Vector3(
            gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider>().center.x,
            gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider>().center.y, -7);
    }
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
        if (other.CompareTag ("Tag"))
            // делаю что-то
        }
void Update () {
        // если не перетаскивается, то постоянно "проходит" по z-координате
        if (gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider> ().center.z < 5) {
            gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider> ().center = new Vector3 (
                gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider> ().center.x,
                gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider> ().center.y,
                gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider> ().center.z + 5 * Time.deltaTime);
}
}
```

Тут `BoxCollider` постоянно проходит некоторое расстояние по оси `Z`. Как только я перетаскиваю наклейку, `BoxCollider` по оси `Z` становится равен `-7`, как только я отпускаю наклейку, `BoxCollider` по оси `Z` перемещается на `5 * Time.deltaTime`. И все это для того, чтобы `OnTriggerEnter()` случился только с ближайшим объектом по оси Z, а не со всеми (или несколькими) по этой же оси. Есть какое-нибудь решение без сложных расчетов и вычислений (для производительности)?

Comment: 8 раз вызывать getcomponent, center, я б начал оптимизировать с этого, закешируй center и boxcollider.  А по вопросу, в момент отпускания кинуть raycast вдоль оси z из точки мыши или центра обьекта, и первый попавший и будет ближайший

Comment: @Xumera_hZ Ну это был временный вариант, я вообще хочу обойтись без манипуляций с коллайдерами. А если из объекта кидать три луча в одну сторну (чтоб определять, что бОльшая часть наклейки закрывает объект), то на производительности это не сильно отразится?

Comment: Не сильно, для большей оптимизации используй перегрузку raycast со всеми аргументами, т.к. внутри проиходит обычный перевызов, если использовать перегрузку raycast с 2 аргументами например

Comment: @Xumera_hZ напиши про рэйкаст в ответе, отмечу как правильный

Answer (score 1):

Есть [Vector3.Distance](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/Vector3.Distance.html), который возвращает расстояние между объектом а и b.

Соответственно сравни расположение объекта с точками и выбери ту, с чем имеется минимальная дистанция.

Comment: Получается, я оставляю длиннющий BoxCollider, затем при контакте (который обрабатываю только при отпущенной кнопки мыши) заношу все объекты в массив, а потом через for нахожу все dist. а затем делаю if (dist == 1){} else if (dist == 2){} и так далее. Я правильно понял?

Comment: `затем делаю if (dist == 1){} else if (dist == 2){}` - что это значит? я не понимаю причем тут ифы........ объекты заносишь в список да.....знаешь как в массиве целых чисел найти минимальное или максимальное? принцип тот же.....

Comment: Все, понял. Попробую сначала с raycast (не хочу лишний раз коллайдеры дергать - пул может слететь), посмотрю что получится.

Comment: @KremSoda ок.  а у тебя 2d или 3d, я что-то не понял)  не забудь, если 2d то надо будет юзать [Vector2.Distance](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/Vector2.Distance.html)  ........ вообще позже перечитаю вопрос (а то я не сильно понял, что там написано :D ) .... может еще что предложу.... так-то raycast вполне себе вариант

Comment: рэйкастом сделал)

Comment: @KremSoda напиши ответ, желательно подробный: как и почему. А через день или два поставь на нем (своём ответе) галочку.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60176/discussion-between-krem-soda-and--).

Answer (score 1):

насколько я понял, ты хочешь реализовать drag and drop. 
если у тебя 2d объект, то ты можешь посмотреть маленький туториал по drag'n'drop:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c47QYgsJrWc (eng)
конечно не оптимальное решение, но для начала сойдет.
удачи!

Comment: отличный урок, но немного не то (там ui) и drag and drop уже сделан, нужно было "найти" только ближайший объект по оси Z среди все на этой оси. Raycast'ом сделал

Answer (score 0):

Найти ответ помог Xumera_hZ, если он его напишет (даже просто комментарий свой скопирует), отмечу его как правильный))
В скрипте наклейки:

```
    RaycastHit hit;
    Ray ray;

    public bool canHit;
    public int someInt;

void Start () {
        canHit = false;
        ray = new Ray (transform.position, Vector3.forward);
    }

public void OnMouseDrag () {
        Vector2 p = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (new Vector2 (Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y));
        gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3 (p.x, p.y, -1);
        }

    void OnMouseDown(){
        canHit = false;
    }
    void OnMouseUp(){
        canHit = true;
    }

void Update () {

        if (canHit)
        {
            ray.origin = transform.position;
            ray.direction = Vector3.forward;
            Debug.DrawRay (transform.position, Vector3.forward * 10);

            if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit, 11)) {
if (hit.collider.gameObject.CompareTag ("Tag")) {

// делаю что-нибудь с объектом, на который попал луч
hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponen<SomeoneScript> ().someInt = someInt; 
// делаю что-нибудь еще

canHit = false;
                }
            }
else // если рэйкаст не встречает объекты
{
// делаю что-нибудь
}
        }

    }
```